# Does the section 1202 qualified small business stock reduce New York, Illinois, or California taxable income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, new-york

Say I sold a small amount of stock that qualifies for [section 1202](http://www.journalofaccountancy.com/Issues/2013/May/20137453.htm). Does this reduce my New York taxable income, or just the federal capital gains amount?

Answer (score 3):

[Multistate Impact of the American Taxpayer Relief Act of 2012](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/us/Documents/Tax/us-tax-mts-alert-multistate-impact-of-the-american-taxpayer-030513.pdf)

In general, states with rolling conformity will follow this change. States with specific date conformity will continue
to follow the date of conformity currently in effect and will not follow the change. A few states may have their own
QSBS rules and will not conform to or be impacted by this provision of the Act. The chart that follows summarizes
these principles as applied to the enumerated states:

STATE: QSBS Exclusion Conformity:
California statutes refer to the IRC QSBS provisions but modify and limit their
applicability, and would not be impacted by this provision of the Act.

However, California’s provisions were ruled unconstitutional in recent litigation
and the California Franchise Tax Board has recently taken the position that gain exclusions
and deferrals will be denied for all open tax years.

Florida Florida does not impose an income tax on individuals and therefore this provision of
the Act is inapplicable and will have no impact.

Illinois Due to its rolling conformity, Illinois follows this provision of the Act.

Because New York effectively provides for rolling conformity to the IRC, through
reference to federal adjusted gross income as the state starting point, New York
effectively follows this provision of the Act.

Texas does not impose an income tax on individuals